# Why does Google use inline JavaScript and CSS?

Tags: javascript, css

I can only see inline CSS and JS while viewing the source code of Google webpage. I don't see any CSS file or JS file being included.

How do they include jquery, plugins etc? (or) Does Google use Jquery?

Comment: google webpage.. which one? the search?

Comment: because using line js and css improves speed , furthermore , a lot of the css content is generated , not actually handcoded in the page.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Google [uses](https://developers.google.com/closure/library/) [Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) to compress its JavaScript.
No, Google certainly does not use jQuery—it is all vanilla JavaScript and (sometimes) [Closure Library](https://developers.google.com/closure/library/).

As for inlining, if JS/CSS is relatively small, it is faster to inline it **to minimize the number of HTTP requests**.

[Google Page Speed Online](https://developers.google.com/pagespeed/) can give you some tips on how to optimize your page.
[mod_pagespeed for Apache](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/module.html) can do many optimizations for you (including content inlining where appropriate).

Comment: “The Closure Library serves as the base JavaScript library for many Google products, including: Gmail, Maps, Docs, Sites, Books, Reader, Blogger, Calendar, Google+, Photos.” https://developers.google.com/closure/library/

Comment: +1 now that's a thorough explanation

Comment: It's quite ironic how the page you linked actually uses jQuery now ;)

Comment: Each time you open a google results page, you download 1/2MB of data. How is that efficient????! The purpose of css and js caching is that it saves bandwidth -- something that is still a problem in many parts of the world! It seems that Google has forgotten this lesson

Answer (score 4):

They most likely use some processing software that converts their development HTML/CSS/JS into the HTML/CSS/JS that we visitors of their site receive.

Many sites do this to some extent (such as compressing the CSS and JS files to reduce their filesize) but it's also possible to inline everything with a processor.

Answer (score 3):

The Google search page (the one with the giant Google logo) is nothing more than a single paged "web app". it uses AJAX to communicate with the server to retrieve it's searches, thus you don't even need to leave the page.

with that said, it makes more sense to load the page (with source squashed) *in one big chunk* (HTML+CSS+JS) rather than use several files for stylesheets, page and scripts.

this is an advantage since it reduces the amount of HTTP requests to *just one file* (rather than have a separate index, and several CSS and JS) and makes the page load fast. and not to mention, that single page is *cachable*. the next time you visit that page, it just pops straight from the cache, and no HTTP request required.

Comment: In that case, why doesn't everyone do inline CSS and JS? Also, considering the odds of someone having the CSS and JS for google.com in their browser cache... ;)

Comment: because not everyone runs a "single paged"/"web-app-like" site. these types of pages are hard to maintain. there are a lot to consider when doing this instead of the traditional page-by-page website

Comment: How's that different from multi-page sites? And why would the cachability differ had they used non-inline CSS and JS? All resources could just as easily "pop straight from the cache", could they not?

Comment: Does that mean, we need not worry about inline css or inline js if its a single page?

Comment: @MRamKumar, why would you need to worry about inline CSS and JS at all?

Comment: @bzlm for the same size of resources, whether in chunk or in separate pieces, which would be faster? calling a single chunk? or calling several pieces of files?

Comment: @bzlm, I heard inline CSS affects SEO.(Though SEO is not at all required for Google, just eager to know, why do they use inline)

Comment: You could use a cached version of Google's homepage a month from now and the chances are it would still work. The static content and engine doesn't change; the ajax requests populate the page each time which have 0 cache time.