# Two divs next to one another, using width 4X%

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place one div next to one another, each one taking half the width of their parent.

I've tried different methods and none of them work!

I tried making the left one floating left, and the right one floating right.

I also tried making them display:inline and inline-block, what is the corrent way to approach this??

Comment: -1: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Rolled back edit.  The divs are not nested.

Comment: this actually seems like a pretty good question.  Not sure what @TiesonT is referring to

Comment: @xaxxon While I suppose it's subjective, I find trying to answer an HTML/CSS question that doesn't include (at least) markup to be much harder to answer, since you have no idea what the OP's source looks like. I've helped with a couple questions where the problem wasn't obvious until real source was added. The link was intended to be helpful; I'm sorry if it comes across as rude...

Comment: @TiesonT. not rude, but it IS a specific question, and with css, there's really only one right way to do it, so if it's not working, it's not really a teaching process from what was attempted before.  with turing complete programming, it's different than with CSS.. which arguably could even not be a topic on SO.

Comment: You should read up on floats a bit more.  Things you want to be together should all float the same direction (left/right).  Left floats and right floats won't necessarily line up because they are looking at different things to figure out where to be.

Answer (score 0):

Here we go

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child1">
    </div>
    <div class="child2">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.child1{
    background: blue;
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
    width: 50%
}
.child2{
    background: red;
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
    width: 50%
}
```

[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/BL5au/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="width:500px;">
    <div style="width:50%; height:100px; background-color:blue; float:left;">left</div>
    <div style="width:50%; height:100px; background-color:red; float:left;">right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Omg please don't do a example with inline style... please don't

Comment: ?? There's nothing wrong with demonstrating something small like this via inline. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9851453/why-does-google-use-inline-javascript-and-css

Comment: There is a simple reason, people who don't know how to do will follow your example, so its better for "padawans" start with the best markup and if he became a "jedi" one day, he can do inline styles where its necessary

Comment: @ViníciusMoraes I think the point was that you never do inline styles, but to answer  a question on SO, it's a succinct way to get the solution across

Comment: lol @ padawan. Yep I see where you are coming from Vinicius, and I agree with that sort of rule of thumb for most things. I just find that learning inline, style block at top of html page, and css files all kinda get lumped in together for me when I teach padawans about css. Thats how I learned it, but I suppose it's all a matter of teaching preference.